# In Powershell what is the idiomatic way of converting a string to an int?

Tags: powershell

The only method I have found is a direct cast:

```
> $numberAsString = "10"
> [int]$numberAsString
10
```

Is this the standard approach in Powershell? Is it expected that a test will be done before to ensure that the conversion will succeed and if so how?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Using .net

```
[int]$b = $null #used after as refence
$b
0
[int32]::TryParse($a , [ref]$b ) # test if is possible to cast and put parsed value in reference variable
True
$b
10
$b.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

note this (powershell coercing feature)

```
$a = "10"
$a + 1 #second value is evaluated as [string]
101 

11 + $a # second value is evaluated as [int]
21
```

Comment: Looks like `[int]::Parse("")` is the only 1 doing it's job with empty strings (throws exception); everything else (`[int]""` / `"" -as [int]` / `int::TryParse("" [ref]...)`) returns `0`.

Comment: Interesting footnote: `[ref]$null` can be used if you're only interested in whether or not it can be casted without doing any conversion.

Answer (score 78):

You can use the -as operator. If casting succeed you get back a number:

```
$numberAsString -as [int]
```

Comment: If cast not succeed always return an INT '0'!

Comment: Actually, if the cast fails it returns $null.  If you then cast that  to [int] (either implicitly or explicitly) you get 0 .

Comment: @mjolinor. rigth! Have tested it with an implicit casted var! Thanks

Comment: Not always, trying to find a good explanation why [int]"" or "" -as [int] gives back 0. "foo" -as [int] gives back nothing.

Comment: That seems to be the way PS coerces a null to int. [int]'' and [int]$null returns 0 also. (disclaimer - WAG follows) =>Looks like it might be to accomodate the way the pipeline returns scalar/array results. $count += $_.count will always work regardless of whether $_ is array or scalar.

Comment: Actually that was not a good comment.  $count += @(<expression>) will always work, even if the expression evaluates to $null.

Comment: @mjolinor I'm aware that [int]$VarThatDosentExist gives back 0 (it's the default value of int), and I know about $null, but i didn't expect an empty string to give the same value.

Comment: That does seem odd, but PS will coerce a string to [int], a null string evaulates to $null, and $null evaluates to 0 as [int].

Answer (score 19):

A quick true/false test of whether it will cast to [int]

```
[bool]($var -as [int] -is [int])
```

Comment: Does not work if `$var = ""`

Answer (score 10):

For me `$numberAsString -as [int]` of @Shay Levy is the best practice, I also use `[type]::Parse(...)` or `[type]::TryParse(...)`

But, depending on what you need you can just put a string containing a number on the right of an arithmetic operator with a int on the left the result will be an Int32:

```
PS > $b = "10"
PS > $a = 0 + $b
PS > $a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

You can use Exception (try/parse) to behave in case of Problem

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably do something like that :

```
[int]::Parse("35")
```

But I'm not really a Powershell guy. It uses the static Parse method from System.Int32. It should throw an exception if the string can't be parsed.

Answer (score -2):

```
$source = "number35"

$number=$null

$result = foreach ($_ in $source.ToCharArray()){$digit="0123456789".IndexOf($\_,0);if($digit -ne -1){$number +=$\_}}[int32]$number
```

Just feed it digits and it wil convert to an `Int32`

Comment: what does `$\_` mean?

Answer (score -2):

Building up on Shavy Levy answer:

```
[bool]($var -as [int])
```

Because $null is evaluated to false (in bool), this statement Will give you true or false depending if the casting succeeds or not.

Comment: Disagree: `[bool]('0' -as [int])` returns `false` although `'0' -as [int]` succeeds!

Comment: `($null -ne ($var -as [int]))` works in all cases except for an empty string, so you need to check for it too `(! (($null -eq ($var -as [int])) -or ($null -eq $var)))`