# Test for function empty return value

Tags: powershell, null

**(edit)** *an empty function does in fact return a null, something led me astray, leaving the question here as a reminder...*

Where $null does not cut it. My scenario is simplest explained as a snippet, I have a function someone wrote

```
function PositiveInt([string]$value) { 
    if ([int]($value) -ge 0) {[int]$value}
}
```

Which returns nothing in the negative case or throws if the input is not a numeric string. How can I test for the return in the negative case? I tried this

```
if ($null -eq (PositiveInt -1)) {
    write-host "not positive :)"
}
```

But it obviously won't work, because no return value is not equal to $null . How can I test if a function or expression simply does not return anything at all? Don't try fix my contrived function, its the absence of "$empty" (sic) I want to do a test for, but cannot because powershell binding does not mandate that a function or even an expression actually returns anything at all?

```
# hacky unclear solution proposed
$temp = @(PositiveInt -1)
if ($temp.length -eq 0) {
    write-host "not positive :)"
}
```

I drew some inspiration from this [In Powershell what is the idiomatic way of converting a string to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700627/in-powershell-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-converting-a-string-to-an-int) posting. but I'm asking a different question I believe. 
Aside from the casting to array workaround, is there a cleaner way?

**(edit)** *Have to admit something environmental or in the actual code context was at play, in PS 5.1 a function call returns $null as @AnsgarWiechers pointed out.*

Comment: As a matter of fact, "no return value" from a function or subexpression *does* equal `$null`.

Comment: @AnswarWiechers this question is because 
if ($null -eq (PositiveInt -1)) {"Yay"} does NOT produce "YAY" - it might work in powershell 4 or powershell 5. But not in my version - hence the question. It should , but I sense I need to wrap the function call somehow.

I'll try again on another machine and award some points. Because it works on fine this computer. (Posh v3) I hope this question is not a dud - in which case I'll have to make an edit as well :)

Comment: Then something else is amiss. The comparison works correctly even on PowerShell v2.

Comment: Have to admit something environmental or in the actual code context was at play, in PS 5.1 a function call returns $null as @AnsgarWiechers pointed out. question ammended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
if ((PositiveInt -1) -eq $null) {
    write-host "not positive :)"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`-is` or `-isnot` type operators](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113273) to check if the result successfully converted to an integer:

```powershell
if( (PositiveInt '-1') -isnot [int] ) {
  write-host 'negative'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you like this?

```
if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty( (PositiveInt -1) ) ) {
    write-host "not positive :)"
}
```

Comment: Kinda looks hacky. It is however testing against [string]$null , which for soem rerason is not working in powershell v2 or v3 - not sure which at the moment.