# In powershell is there a way to check if a user's input has a decimal in it?

Tags: powershell, decimal

I am writing a code and a part of it asks the user inputs a number and I have to check if the number is a decimal. If the number is a decimal than output has to say "this is a decimal number" and if the number is not a decimal than the output says "This is not a decimal number". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will probably get a better response if you post the code you've tried already. Please read the help topics to get an idea of how you might improve this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is `"1.0"` a decimal number or not? In other words, do you want to base this on the property of the input or the value itself?

Answer (score 2):

Since the cat is out of the bag now you could just attempt to cast the value to a `[decimal]`. If successful return `$true`

```
function IsDecimal($value){
    Try{
        [decimal]$value | Out-Null
        $true
    } Catch {
        $false
    }
}

IsDecimal "10"
IsDecimal "1.2"
IsDecimal "bagels"
```

## output

```
True
True
False
```

So you could use this in other parts of your code if need be

```
If(IsDecimal $string){Write-Host "Stuff"}
```

You can read more about casting in from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700627/in-powershell-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-converting-a-string-to-an-int). Lots of good answers here that don't need to be repeated.

In that regard

```
If($value -as [decimal]){Write-Host "Valid decimal"}else{Write-Host "Not valid decimal"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are trying to pass number from command line and checking then it would look something like below.

```html
PS C:\> .\Untitled1.ps1 123
Does not contains '.'

PS C:\> .\Untitled1.ps1 123.24
Contains '.'

Untitled1.ps1
============

if ($args[0].GetType() -eq  [System.Double])
{
    Write-Host "Contains '.'";
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Does not contains '.'";
}
```

Comment: I would say that "10" is a valid decimal

Comment: I think he just wants to check if the number contains '.' or not. Let me know if that is not true.

Comment: @ Matt: What did you change in code? I am not seeing any change then what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Your question can work two ways. You are looking to determine is a number is a decimal. Eiter you mean the type or you mean if the number has decimals.

Lets work with variable `$Sum` and $Sum holds the value `2.5`

In case you want to know the type you could just enter:

```
$sum.GetType().Name
```

In case you want a true or false you could enter:

```
if (($sum - ($sum -as [int])) -ne 0) {"$false"}Else {$True}
```

You see, by casting $Sum as an [int] it would automatically be rounded (in this case to 2). So by extracting ($Sum -as [int]) from $Sum you would end up with an outcome of 2.5-2 = 0.5 which means that sum must be anything else but a rounded number.