# Why does multiplication does not work with Read-Host value

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

```
$table_num = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the table number you want to get printed'
for ($i=1; $i-lt 11; $i++){
    $ans = ($table_num*$i)
    write "$table_num*$i=$ans"
}
```

Above is the script which I was trying to execute and I get the result as below:

```
Enter the table number you want to get printed: 5
5*1=5
5*2=55
5*3=555
5*4=5555
5*5=55555
5*6=555555
5*7=5555555
5*8=55555555
5*9=555555555
5*10=5555555555
```

I am new to scripting and help me with my code.

Comment: Compare `5 * 10` and `'5' * 10`.

Comment: Please pick a meaningful question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers!!

Actually I have added the data type `int`. And the script is good as below.

```
$table_num = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the table number you want to get printed'

        For ($i=1; $i-lt 11; $i++){
        $ans = ([int]$table_num*$i)
            write "$table_num  *  $i =  $ans"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you did not point out what is the expected behavior I am not sure if I solve your issue, but I guess you want something like that

```
$table_num_str = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the table number you want to get printed'
$table_num = [int]::Parse($table_num_str)
for ($i=1; $i-lt 11; $i++){
    $ans = ($table_num*$i)
    write "$table_num*$i=$ans"
}
```

which when entered '5' results in

```
Enter the table number you want to get printed: 5
5*1=5
5*2=10
5*3=15
5*4=20
5*5=25
5*6=30
5*7=35
5*8=40
5*9=45
5*10=50
```

So the problem was that `Read-Host` returns a `string` which when multiplied with X results in that string repeated X times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in type returned by Read-Host cmdlet.

```
$num = read-host
$num.GetType()
```

It returns `Object[]` which is implicitly converted to other types if required. Type is also converted to first argument type when binary operator is used (+, -, *). There are no * operator in `object[]` type. That's why it's converted to string and THEN multiplied. If first argument is int, PowerShell tries to convert it to int as well. You can tweak your code to use this conversion rules. Take a look at script below:

```
$table_num = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the table number you want to get printed'
1..10 | % { write "$table_num*$_=$($_*$table_num)" }
```

It also produces:

```
5*1=5
5*2=10
5*3=15
5*4=20
5*5=25
5*6=30
5*7=35
5*8=40
5*9=45
5*10=50
```

Answer (score -1):

To have a working calculation you need a number, not a string.

Multiplying a string gives this kind of result :

```
"test" * 5 # returns testtesttesttesttest
```

You could fix your issue like this:

```
[int]$input_number = $null

$input_string = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the table number you want to get printed'

while(-not [int]::TryParse($input_string, [ref]$input_number)) {
    $input_string = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a number'
}

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i++) {
    $ans = ($input_number * $i)
    Write-Host "$input_number * $i = $ans"
}
```

`[int]::TryParse($input_string, [ref]$input_number)` will try to parse the input string as an `integer` and store the value in `$input_number`. As long as this fails (because of a bad input), the script will ask for a new input.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700627/in-powershell-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-converting-a-string-to-an-int) for additional information.

Comment: your code loop and print result same if not integer is write by user and error raised

Answer (score -2):

```
do {
    $table_num = read-host "Enter the table number you want to get printed"
    $a = ""
    if( ![int32]::TryParse( $table_num , [ref]$a ) ) {
        Write-Host "Only integers please"
    }
} until ($a -gt 0)

1..10 | % { Write-Host "$table_num*$_=$($_*$table_num)" }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are useless. You need to explain, what is wrong, and how your code addresses the issue. -1, because *"this answer is not useful"*.

Comment: _And_ negative values are not _evil_.

Comment: Its exagered, what explanation would you ? All is already gived by others... For negative its not false, i agree, but what interret.... A mutiplication table never negative  :)

Comment: My point is that you should not _reject_ negative values because they don't break the script. As for the explanation, we all try to make complete and stand-alone answers around here, that's just how it goes. And your explanation _might_ introduce some useful detail missing in the others :).

Comment: 666 is evil, and it's not negative value :P

Comment: (in your code, you introduce at least 5 concepts OP may not know about : `do/until`, `TryParse()`, the range operator `..`, the pipeline, and the `%` alias for `ForEach-Object`)

Comment: I learn by other persons and by other ways of programming, not you? ;)

Comment: As someone only starting out in scripting/programming, this answer is only helpful if A) The code commented to illustrate what is going on and B) The viewer is resourceful enough to use `Get-Help` or TechNet.microsoft.com to find out more about what the code is doing.

Comment: I'll try to be better the next time ^^