# How to print data from hashTable with variable?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

i'd like to print data from table. When i use Read-Host this code not working.

How I can make this?
(Sorry for my english).

my Code is here:

```
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$SqlConnection.Close()
$cureentData = Get-Date -format "yyyy-M-d"

$table = $DataSet.Tables[0]

$i=0;
$hash = @{};     
foreach ($row in $table)
{

 $hash.Add(($i),(@{ 
'app_id' = ($row.app_id) 
 'app_guid' = ($row.app_guid) 
 'app_nazwa_pliku' = ($row.app_nazwa_pliku) 
})) 

Write-Host [$i] "Nr sprawy:" $row.sp_numer "Zakończono:" $row.ak_zakonczono"-" $row.app_guid ;
$i++;
}

 if($table.Rows.Count -gt 1)
  {
   $selected = Read-Host -Prompt 'Który z plików chcesz zmienić?';
   ($hash.$selected).app_guid; #working only if $selected is $selected=5 without Read-Host
   ($hash[$selected]).app_guid; #working only if $selected is $selected=5 without Read-Host
   ($hash.5).app_guid; #working, but i need use variable
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: You are not showing enough of your code. How do you read in the `$table` variable? Do you initiate the `$i` variable at some point?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I updated my code. Data are download from DB and put to DataSet. $table is $dataSet.Tables[0]. $i is initiate befor foreach

Comment: Your title does not match your issue I think. `$selected` is a string. If you want to use it like an int you need to change it somehow. `[int]$selected = Read-Host...`. You can have casting issues if you type the wrong thing into prompt though.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410213/why-does-multiplication-does-not-work-with-read-host-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## $selected is not an integer

`Read-Host` will always return strings. You built your hashtable with *numerical keys*. So, in its simplest form, you need to coerce integers from your input.

```
[int]$selected = Read-Host -Prompt 'Który z plików chcesz zmienić?';
```

or

```
$selected = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Który z plików chcesz zmienić?') -as [int];
```

Beware that since you can type anything you want into `Read-Host` you should do some data validation before attempting to use the data as an integer.

## Change the hash table

You could also reduce this complexity by using strings in your hash table generation as well

```
$hash.Add(("$i"),(@{
```

Using this approach you don't have to make changes to the `Read-Host` prompt output

## Improve your choice method

You might be able to [improve your choice system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479553/select-option-from-array/31482033#31482033) depending on the required complexity of your task.

Answer (score 1):

your problem appears to be the type of the item used as a key. `Read-Host` returns a `[string]` ... so the number you get from it is a numeric string, not an `[int]`. coerce it to an `[int]` and the lookup works. [*grin*] here's an example ...

```
$HashTable = @{}
foreach ($Index in 0..10)
    {
    $HashTable.Add($Index, 
        @{
        Pow2 = [math]::Pow($Index, 2)
        Pow3 = [math]::Pow($Index, 3)
        })
    }

$HTKey = [int](Read-Host 'Enter a number from 0 to 10 to see the cube of it ')

$HashTable[$HTKey].Pow3
```

number entered = `3`
result = `27`