# Powershell command to check if the data type of variable is integer, if it has characters it should respond with a message "Enter Only number"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
[int]$name = Read-Host Enter the KB number
If ($name -is [int]) { 
    wusa /uninstall /kb:$name
    write-Host "This will uninstall windows update KB$name"
} else {
    write-Host "Enter only the number"
}
```

Here in this PowerShell scripts, whenever a characters is typed is returns an error instead of message "Enter only the number".

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop> .\Test.ps1
45454
Enter the KB number: asfs
Cannot convert value "asfs" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.ps1:5 char:1
+ [int]$name = Read-Host Enter the KB number
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

This will uninstall windows update KB0

Comment: Your issue is that in your definition of the variable, you are already defining it as an integer and if you enter a string, there will be a conversion error. Eitehr silence the error by defining `$erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue"` before definition, or define the variable as an int later.

Comment: To test this, run the definition command (`[int]$name = Read-Host Enter the KB number`) in powershell console and enter a string. The same error will occur

Comment: if any answer helps you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @NekoMusume Thanks for your response. The error message returns the value "0" which is integer. So If we use the syntax $erroractionpreference = "silentlycontinue" before the variable, the code doesnt go to the else statement. It returns with a message stating that "This will uninstall KB0", kindly help.

Comment: @SreeRam On my second answer, I don't see what could cause that since it checks if `$name` is `[int]`, however, on my first answer if you silently continue, the `$?` may not work as intended but both should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing is cause by this:

```
[int]$name = Read-Host Enter the KB number
^^^^^
```

By defining the int variable type, any non-int input will cause an error. For example:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> [int]$test = read-host
ABC
Cannot convert value "ABC" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:1
+ [int]$test = read-host
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Powershell tries to convert the string input to the type `System.Int32` but since it is not possible as the input is a string, this error is caused which also causes the variable to not be defined whatsoever. If you are going to define it as a `int`, do it after the variable was initially defined like so:

```
:loop while ($name = read-host Enter the KB number)
    {
    $name -as [int] | findstr $name
    if ($?)
        {[int]$name = $name; break loop}
    else
        {Write-Output "Invalid Input"}
    } 
wusa /uninstall /kb:$name
write-Host "This will uninstall windows update KB$name"
}
```

or alternatively you can do:

```
:loop while ($name = read-host Enter the KB number){
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    [int]$name = $name
    if (!($name -is [int]))
    {echo "Invalid input"} 
    else 
    {break loop}
    }
wusa /uninstall /kb:$name
write-Host "This will uninstall windows update KB$name"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is any command present to test if the value is integer or not. But you can use regular expression to check specific type of data. Here I used regex to match only integer type value. You can use the below code

```
$i = 0
do {
    If ( $i -ne '0' ) { Write-Host 'Enter only Number' } 
$i = 1
$name = Read-Host 'Enter the KB Number'
} until ( $name -match '\b\d+\b')
wusa /uninstall /kb:$name
```

Comment: The test you can do is demonstrated in the question at the second row.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declared `$name` as a variable that can only accept numerical values. Try this code:

```
$name = Read-Host Enter the KB number
[int]$number = $null
if ([int32]::TryParse($name, [ref]$number)) # test if is possible to cast and put parsed value in reference variable
{
    wusa /uninstall /kb:$name
    Write-Host "This will uninstall windows update KB$name"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Enter only the number"
}
```

I choosed this way to convert the input value to the numerical value accoding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9700814/7817074).

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the type declaration of `$Name` and keep the type check :)

```
$name = Read-Host Enter the KB number
if ($Name -is [int]) { 
  Write-Output "Uninstalling Windows update KB$Name"
  wusa /uninstall /kb:$Name
} else {
  Write-Output "Enter only the number"
}
```