# Checking if a string can/cannot be converted to int/float

Tags: powershell, casting, powershell-7.0

**I am using PowerShell 7.1.4 and I wanna check if a string can be converted to a number.**

**Something like:**

```
$age = Read-Host "age"

if(![int]$age) {
    Write-Host "$age is not a number"
}
```

**I came from JavaScript so don't mind the "!" if its wrong, and I just started learning PowerShell.**

Comment: `![int]$age` is a perfectly valid expression in PowerShell, but it will accept/cast _any_ string that can be converted to `[int]` in PowerShells grammar, which may not fit your strict definition of "number" :) Try `[int]''`, `[int]'1e4'`, `[int]'30s'`, `[int]'0xAB'`

Comment: Hello! All input taken by `Read-Host` is of type *string*, unless explicitly specified to type `[int]`. Such as `$age = (Read-Host -Prompt "age") -as [int]`, or casting the type: `[int]$age`. In other words, you can type constrain it to explicitly be of type `[int]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Powershell what is the idiomatic way of converting a string to an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700627/in-powershell-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-converting-a-string-to-an-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **`$age -as [int]`**, which returns `$null` if conversion to the RHS type isn't possible, so that `$null -eq ($age -as [int])` is only `$true` if the conversion is *not* possible (see **`-as`**, the [conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators)):

```
if ($null -eq ($age -as [int])) { Write-Host "$age is NOT a number." }
```

If you also want to *save the converted value*, you can take advantage of PowerShell's ability to use assignments as expressions:

```
if ($null -eq ($ageNumber = $age -as [int])) { Write-Host "$age is NOT a number." }
```

**Caveat**: **`-as` and `[int]` casts convert the *empty* or *blank* (all-whitespace) strings (as well as `$null`) to `0`**. (Try `'' -as [int]`, `'  ' -as [int]`, and `$null -as [int]`).
To avoid that:

- either: use the .NET approach shown in the next section
- or: add an additional check to detect these cases:

```
if ('' -eq $age.Trim() -or $null -eq ($age -as [int])) { Write-Host "$age is NOT a number." }
```

---

A **less PowerShell-idiomatic, but stricter alternative** would be to use the [`[int]::TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32.TryParse) .NET method:

```
if (-not [int]::TryParse($age, [ref] $null)) { Write-Host "$age is NOT a number." }
```

If you also want to *save the converted value*, initialize an output variable and pass it in lieu of `$null`:

```
$ageNumber = $null  # Initialize the output variable (type doesn't matter).
if (-not [int]::TryParse($age, [ref] $ageNumber)) { Write-Host "$age is NOT a number." }
```

As implied above, this method does *not* recognize empty and blank strings as an integer.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`!` is a valid PowerShell operator; its alias is [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators)

- PowerShell implicitly converts its operand to a Boolean (`[bool]`), so a caveat with respect to integers is that `! 0` is also `$true`, even though `0` is a valid integer.
- See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversions.

The problem is that an `[int]` *cast* causes a *statement-terminating error* when its operand can *not* be converted to the specified type. The use of the `-as` operator avoids this problem.

For the sake of completeness: it is possible - though not advisable here - to use a [`try { ... } catch { ... }` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) enclosed in `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), to catch the error:

```
if ($null -eq $(try { [int] $age } catch {})) { Write-Host "$age is NOT a number." }
```